# О словосочетании "ехать на Москву"

Tags: семантика, словосочетания

В каких контекстах возможно сочетание "ехать на Москву"? Может ли оно употребляться, когда рассматриваются рейсы железнодорожного транспорта? Когда речь идет о военном походе?

Answer (score 1):

Рассматривать можно по отношению к *железнодорожному рейсу* (как направлению или дороге "на что-то"), но не к *едущему поездом на Москву* человеку: в таком выражении ключевым является словосочетание "поезд на Москву" (оно довольно устойчиво), а не "едущему на Москву [человеку]" (упрощение на грани просторечия). О поезде можно сказать "*идёт* на Москву" (не "едет").

Comment: А можно то же сказать о наземном транспорте? Автобус идет на Преображенскую площадь. И возможно ли сочетание с "ходит"? Поезда ходят на Москву, автобусы на Саларьево.

Comment: Так можно сказать о конкретном автобусе, напр. если кто-то интересуется, куда по какому фиксированному маршруту, в направлении какого населённого пункта он идёт (внутри города "на площадь" не совсем подходит; лучше "к площади такой-то", чтобы не путалось с буквальным выездом на площадь).

Answer (score 1):

В описании военных походов указанный оборот вполне уместен -- но лишь при условии замены "ехали" на "шли" (или на "двигались").

Скажем, "гитлеровские полчища шли на Москву".

К слову сказать, употребление предлога "на" в военном контексте является очень древним. Вспомним былинное "иду на вы" или фразу с берестяной грамоты: "литва поднялась на карелу".